# Input path doesn't exist in pyspark for hadoop path

Tags: visual-studio, pyspark, hadoop2

Am trying to get the fetch the file from hdfs in pyspark using visual studio code...

1. i have checked through jps all the nodes are in active status only.
2. my file path in hadoop is 
   hadoop fs -cat  emp/part-m-00000

   1,A,ABC
   2,B,ABC
   3,C,ABC
3. and core-site.xml is 
   fs.default.name
   hdfs://localhost:9000
4. am fetching the above mentioned file through visual studio code in pyspark..

but am getting error like

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/emp/part-m-00000

please help me

i have tried giving the hadoop path

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sc= SparkContext('local','example')
hc = HiveContext(sc)
tf1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/emp/part-m-00000")
print(tf1.first())
```

i need to get the file from hadoop

Comment: `emp/part-m-00000` is a relative path, try to find its absolute path, for example: `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/...../emp/part-m-00000`

Comment: how to find absoulte path, could you help me out this

Comment: just add your HDFS home folder, usually `/user/<username>`, <username> is either setup by your shell env `$HADOOP_USER_NAME` or your login shell user. you can check `hdfs dfs -ls /user` and see if you can find your name there, and then use `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/<username>/emp/part-m-00000` to access that file.

Comment: oh.. Thank you, am able to access the hdfs like you said.